# How to properly put a List<Object> in a Spring form:select form:options?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-form

I want to put a List of objects Discipline in a form:select and link the selected Discipline value to the path:"discipline" of the Grade object on submit.

This is how i do it now, linking the grade.discipline.id to the discipline.id. It's working, i've used debug on server and saw how the discipline from the grade object gets the discipline object. But i wonder if there is an "out of the book way", not just my improvisation.

The addGrade.jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="grade">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Value = </th>
            <td><form:input path="value"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="value"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Select discipline: </th>
            <td colspan = "2">
                <form:select path="discipline.id">
                    <c:forEach items="${disciplines}" var="d">
                        <option value="${d.id}">${d.name}</option>"
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="discipline"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

The GradeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addGrade", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addGradeGet (Model model, HttpSession session){
    //this.populateDefaultModel(session);
    List<Discipline> disciplines = disciplineService.findAll();
    Student student = (Student)session.getAttribute("student");
    if(student==null)
        return "redirect:/showStudent.html";
    model.addAttribute("disciplines",disciplines);
    model.addAttribute("currentStudent",student);
    model.addAttribute("grade",new Grade());
    return "addGrade";
}   
@RequestMapping(value = "/addGrade", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addGrade(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("grade") Grade grade,
        BindingResult result, Model model){
    List<Discipline> disciplines = disciplineService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("disciplines",disciplines);

    /*if we found a grade of the current student
     that has the same discipline as the new grade that we try to add
     then we are not allowed to add it
     */
    Student student = (Student) model.asMap().get("currentStudent");

    grade.setStudent(student);

    if(gradeService.findByStudentAndDiscipline(grade)!=null){
        result.rejectValue("discipline", "duplicate");
    }
    if(!(result.hasErrors()) ){
        gradeService.save(grade);
        return "redirect:/students.html";
    }
    else{
        return "addGrade";
    }
}
```

The object Discipline:

```
@Entity
public class Discipline {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="discipline", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();
// getters and setters ..... 
}
```

The object Grade:

```
@Entity
public class Grade {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Range(min=1, max=10)
@NotNull
private int value;
@ManyToOne
private Student student;
@ManyToOne
private Discipline discipline;
// getters and setters .... 
}
```

I know i should use the:

```
<form:select path="discipline">
    <form:options items="${disciplines}"/>
</form:select>
```

I did try it, putting the disciplineHashMap in the discipline attribute for this:

```
List<Discipline> disciplines = disciplineService.findAll();
Map<Discipline,String> disciplinesHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Discipline,String>();
for (Discipline temp:disciplines){
    disciplinesHashMap.put(temp, temp.getName());           
}
model.addAttribute("disciplines",disciplinesHashMap);
```

I get the page, with all the proper labels but when i try to submit i get a nullPointer exception at one of my methods in GradeService that is searching for a discipline value of my grade object, method called in the POST method of addGrade(also on debug on server i see that the grade object has the discipline field as null)... so, that means that i didn't managed to link the discipline value to the object:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.app.service.GradeServiceImpl.findByStudentAndDiscipline(GradeServiceImpl.java:31)
```